# Overriding LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "page-name" for a specific function in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a base.py file that states a default redirection page when the user registers and gets logged in.

**base.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "index"
```

I want to create to possibility for a user that connects from a specific page `page_1` to signup/login directly from this page.

When they sign up/login they will be redirected to the same `page1` which will show a different content based on whether the user is authenticated or not. (if authenticated they get content, if not they get the signup/login prompt)

The problem I am running into (I think) is that when a user register from `page_1`, this user is redirected to `index` page as defined in my base.py.

Is there a way to override the base.py for a specific function?

I left my latest attempt `request.session['LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL'] = url`. Which didnt work.

```
def show_venue(request, page_id):       
        
#REGISTER USER FROM VENUE  
url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
print(f'url ={url}')
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active=True

        user.save()
        user = authenticate(username = form.cleaned_data['username'],
                            password = form.cleaned_data['password1'],)
        login(request,user)
        request.session['LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL'] = url
    else:
        for error in list(form.errors.values()):
            messages.error(request, error)
  
else:
    form = RegisterForm()
```

Comment: The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is only used if the `LoginView` doesn't get a `next` GET parameter (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url).  If you can put something like `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="url_you_want" />` in the template, that should work.

Comment: Hi Raphael, thanks for the answer it worked. As per your example, I used your example and used`request.get_full_path` to get my current URL `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />`. Feel free to propose it as an answer and I will validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is only used if the LoginView doesn't get a next GET parameter according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url). If you can, put something like `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="url_you_want" />` in the template, that should work.  The url can be generated by the view, or any value you want.  In your case you did `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />` using Django's [get_full_path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path).

It might also help to know that the reverse is also true.  If you were *trying* to set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to a value, and your page does *not* go there, it's because there *is* a `next` parameter already, for example if one uses [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) the supplied templates for login, etc... have the `next` parameter built in.